# Number of terms in the expansion of $(1+x^3+x^5) ^n$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How can we find the number of terms in the expansion of $(1+x^3+x^5)^n$ ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Number_of_multinomial_coefficients

Comment: Since 3 and 5 are relatively prime, all powers of $x$ occur (from $x^0$ to $x^{5n}$), except a few near the beginning and perhaps a few near the end.

Comment: @Gedgar probably more near the end, there might be many missing between $3n$ and $5n$...

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Multinomial would give n+2 C 2 ,wouldn't it be wrong in this case?

Comment: @GEdgar:I am aware of that but what is the formal procedure for this?

Comment: For $n \ge 3$, the number of terms is $5n-5$.

Comment: @GEdgar:How did you come up with this formula?

Comment: Isn't it time for YOU to do some work?

Comment: @GEdgar: Actually I did a lot of work,manually checked for n=20 ,found the answer to be 95,and tried different approaches,but couldn't get anywhere,I tried dividing expression by various powers of x,tried factorizing it,tried involving roots of unity ,but got nowhere,just tell me the right approach

Comment: @GEdgar:I mean the method used for solving such questions

Comment: @GEdgar:I also figured that as 3 and 5 are co prime for n=20 ,powers of x n=1,n=2,n=4,n=7,n=94,n=97 are the terms can't be formed .I tried all 15k+ r forms of numbers ,found them all of them can be represented by a linear combination of powers of 3 and 5

Answer (score 4):

Since all coefficients are positive, there is no concern about terms possibly canceling out.

It is easy to show that $(1+x^3+x^5)^3$ has 10 terms. You can either list them out, or use ${5 \choose 2} = 10$.

Proceed by induction, to show that if $n\geq 3$, then $f_n(x) = (1+x^3 + x^5)^n$ has $5n-5$ terms.

**Hint:** Going from $k$ to $k+1$, all coefficients which existed in $f_k$ will also exist in $f_{k+1}$.

**Hint:** Show that $f_{k+1}$ has 5 additional terms. Which 5 are these?

**Hint:** $5(k+1)$ is one of the additional terms. Do you see why? What other additional terms are there?

Comment: why does (5 c 2) give the correct number of terms for n=3

Comment: why should Multinomial hold ?

Comment: @user1907531 I'm not using Multinomial. You need to do a bit or work. As stated, the easiest way is to multiply it out, through there is an easy theoretical arguement that is guided by the rest of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$(1+x^3+x^5)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^{3 k} (1+ x^2)^k$$

There are $n+1$ terms.  For the $k$th term, there are $k+1$ terms.  Therefore, there are

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (k+1) = \frac12 (n+1)(n+2)$$

terms before combining. However, there are many terms that will combine (i.e., like powers).  To get an accurate count, then, we must figure out what those powers are.

Let's write, ignoring the coefficients, the powers by value of $k$:

$$(1+x^3+x^5)^n = \begin{array}\\ 1  \\ x^3 & x^5\\x^6 & x^8 & x^{10}\\ x^9 & x^{11} & x^{13} & x^{15}\\ x^{12} & x^{14} & x^{16} & x^{18} & x^{20}\\  x^{15} & x^{17} & x^{19} & x^{21} & x^{23} & x^{25} \end{array}$$

and so on.  In general, we want to find all values of $3 k+2 \ell$ that overlap for different lattice points $(k,\ell)$.  Note that we have a first combining when $k=5$ (which explains why my test for small $n$ worked); $(5,0)$ and $(3,3)$.

Unfortunately, I know of no closed for expression for the number, $h(m)$, of pairs of lattice points $(k,\ell)$ that have $3 k+2 \ell$ being equal to a given integer $m$.  The best that I can see written is

$$\frac12 (n+1)(n+2) - \sum_{m=0, m=3 k+2 \ell}^{5 n} [h(m)-1]$$

Comment: Not true. Just check [$n=6$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E5%29%5E6) which has 25 terms. You have double counted a lot of terms. Also, your first equation should be $(1 + x^5)^k$?

Comment: @CalvinLin: see my additions.  And to answer your question, no.  $$(x^3+x^5)^k = x^{3 k} (1+x^2)^k$$

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of expanding it as $[ (1+x^5) + x^3 ] ^k$, but of course the degrees would then be wrong. The similarity of the expressions intrigue me now :)